# Is there any other way to retrieve data from a webservice except JSON and XML?

Tags: java, android, database, cloud

I used JSON parser to retrieve data from my website database. But I want to know if there is any other to retrieve data from webservice except JSON and XML methods?

Comment: Are you making you own back end? If so you can look into google protobuffers

Comment: Sure. You can download a binary file, html view, plain text, etc from a web service.

Comment: You can also use protocol buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Answer (score 1):

JSON and XML are not methods, they are formats of data presentation and the most commonly used ones when it comes to obtaining data from a web service. Even if there exists, some other format, it's not very relevant since pretty much 99% of the client applications using these web service endpoints would support either of these two or with the pronounced shift to REST mostly JSON.

Comment: You can always accept the answer, if it meets your requirement.